# PayPal - Users can change price before checkout

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I'm having a small problem on my website. I want to make it so right before users check out they can change some options to their own liking, which edits the final price. I have this working, but the user can easily inspect element and change the amount to pay on the PayPal button. This is my HTML for the button right now:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="agservers7@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="VPS">
  <input type="hidden" id='priceValue' name="amount" value="0.99">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

So, for price updating, I do this in JavaScript. The `updateFinalPrice()` function is called when the user changes the options that they have:

```
  function updateFinalPrice(){
    var mainPrice = 24.99
    var finalPriceElement = $("#finalPrice")
    var finalPrice = addedRAM + mainPrice
    finalPrice = (finalPrice).toFixed(2)
    finalPriceElement.text("$" + finalPrice)

    $('#priceValue').attr("value", finalPrice) // Changes amount value of paypal button
}
```

So this works overall, but once the user has set all their options, they could just change the value of the amount input to whatever they want to pay, which is clearly an issue.

I understand I could do this on the server, but I don't understand how to go about doing that when the price of the item changes depending on what the user sets their options to.

A good example of what I am looking for can be found [here](https://www.nfoservers.com/order-virtual-dedicated-server.php). However I want it so right after the user has set the options to their liking, they click the Paypal button, without being able to change the price. Any help is realty appreciated.

Comment: maybe you should send the items, not the price, to the server, and do the math there.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you would use the IPN API to validate the order once it is submitted. Basically the IPN API lets you intercept the order and validate it as well as handling any other order related tasks like inventory management or sending out notifications.

When a customer places an order on your site they are redirected to PayPal to complete the payment. The order is first sent to the PayPal server which sends a message to your configured IPN listener script.

The IPN listener script should validate the order, including all pricing, before allowing it to proceed. The listener script will send back a reply message stating whether the order should proceed.

All of this is way out of scope for a stackoverflow answer and you really need to read the IPN documentation from PayPal and implement your listener correctly.

Good places to start:

- [Introducing IPN - PayPal API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)
- [Instant Payment Notification - IPN](https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside)

Answer (score 1):

Have your checkout form submit to itself, and then send the data to PayPal via a redirect:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $params = array(
        'amount' => '0.99',
        'business' => 'agservers7@gmail.com',
        'cmd' => '_xclick',
        'currency_code' => 'USD',
        'item_name' => 'VPS',
    );
    header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?'.http_build_query($params));
}
```

As previously suggested, you should also have a callback that validates IPN requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can actually check which product request is coming in the server using its id from your product table, and create some predefined price values for each product in your table, and then set the amount value to that price from your database, instead of taking it from clint side form

Answer (score 0):

The best and proper way to perform checkout with Final Price is that, you pass all your item ids to Server side script and calculate Final price their before sending users to Paypal.

**NOTE:** There must be Server side script which should calculate and send price to any payment process.

Answer (score 0):

One way to help stop it is to make a seperate page, (called paynow.php or something), and make your button link to there, (with some post data of course).

So, paynow.php should look like

```
<form method="POST" action="http://paypal url here.com" id="paynow">
    <input name="your paypal inputs here"/>
</form>
<script id="payscript">
    document.getElementById('paynow').submit();
    document.getElementById('paynow').remove();
    document.getElementById('payscript').remove();
</script>
```

The above code should make it so that by the time a user inspects and changes an element, the form would have already submitted and selfdestructed its own code. HOWEVER, you cannot rely on this, people can easily disable javascript, and you should definitely do some server-side pricing checks after the payment. Here's a simple PHP IF statement you can use in your IPN page that demonstrates this.

```
if($_POST['mc_gross'] === "3.99") {
    // payment success! your processes here.
    // (NOTE: this code is not the complete IPN script!)
    // Use this code when paypal returns VERIFIED from IPNPB
}
```